# How to convert Keras h5 to PyTorch pth format?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, pytorch

I have trained a feature extractor in Keras and saved the weights as a h5 file. Now I want to load the same weights into the same model created and initialized in PyTorch for performance comparisons. Is there any way I can convert the h5 file to pth file so I can load that into the PyTorch model?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 2):

*You must be careful with the versions from TF and PyTorch (as some commands may be different).*

Basically you must:

1 - Know your layer and activation structure on Keras:

You can get the layer information with:

```
model_keras.summary()
```

If you can't get info about activation functions, try:

```
for layer in model_keras.layers:
    print(layer.output)
```

2 - Build a model on PyTorch that has the same layer structure (and activation) as on Keras

3 - The recently created PyTorch model (let's say `model_pyt`) has different weights and biases from your model on Keras, so **you must copy those weights and biases from the Keras model to PyTorch model**:

**BE CAREFUL HERE, PYTORCH WEIGHTS ARE TRANSPOSED IN RELATION TO KERAS WEIGHTS**

Then, for example, copying a weight would be like:

```
model_pyt.layer1.weight.data = torch.tensor(model_keras.layers[0].get_weights()[0].T)
```

And for the bias:

```
model_pyt.layer1.bias.data = torch.tensor(model_keras.layers[0].get_weights()[1])
```

repeat that for all layers.

Then, your PyTorch model has the same architecture and weights as the Keras model and *might* behave in the same way.